# How to enable Pantheon's single-click behavior for the file chooser dialogs?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I know that there a plenty of questions here on how to *disable* the single-click behaviour of the *Pantheon file manager*. But, in fact, I really like it, and I'm rather confused by the fact, that this behaviour is implemented inconsistently in Freya: Particularly, we still have to use a double click to choose a file in a *dialog*. This is highly inconvenient. Can the single-click behaviour be enabled for the file chooser dialogs too?

Answer (score 2):

The Pantheon file-chooser still uses the native Gtk Filechooser widget and this seems to hard code the double click behaviour. So it is not possible to change this at present by changing a setting.

It would be possible however to amend the coding for Pantheon filechooser so that it sets the behaviour to match that setting for Files.

A bug report will need to be raised concerning this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files